# How do i do unit test on else statement that just return. - Nodejs, Sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I am doing my unit testing in nodejs using sinon.

How do test for the else portion for my task1.js? It is suppose to be if my count is not 0, i will proceed to my own processing, else I end my task.

I can mock my getbookForUpdateCount to return count values but what comes next?

How do i ensure that that path is taken?

**Task1.js:**

```
function updateInfo() {

    bookDao.getbookForUpdateCount(updateCountParams, function (results) {

        console.log("Step 1: " + results[0].RECCOUNT + " for updates!".blue);
        //1. Get count. If > 0, proceed. else end task.
        if (results[0].RECCOUNT > 0) {

            ...
            //some other functions
        }
        else {
            //no record to be processed.
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You'll need to do two tests, one to test when the condition is truthy, and another for when it isn't. I'm assuming you're using some variant of `sinon.stub().yields()`? If so you just need to change what the stub yields. Could you share the test code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question in the following way: The function you want to test will, depending on certain conditions, either have some effect or alternatively just "do nothing".  Now, you want to test the case that the software runs into the "do nothing" path.  But, you are not sure how to validate in your test code that the function just did nothing.

The validation is, simply said. just to verify that no effect has taken place.  If, for example, the effect is the modification of a global variable, then the non-effect is that the global variable keeps its value.  If the effect is that a method on a certain object is called, then the non-effect is that the respective method was not called - mock libraries offer checks for exactly this case, namely to check that a certain function was *not* called.  If the effect is that some data is entered into a data base, then the non-effect is, that the respective data can not be found in the data base (although this is not a unit-testing example, but an integration testing example).